# How to add tabindex to xe:djComboBox

Tags: xpages

I need to add a tabIndex to a page that contains several Dojo Combo Boxes from the XPages Extension Library.  It seems that the tabIndex property is not supported.

The XSP editor says it is an "unknown property" and "not defined on tag ".

Does anyone know how to add this property?

*Note: In this application, jQuery is not available to use.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me

```
<xe:djComboBox id="djComboBox1" tabIndex="3"></xe:djComboBox>
<xe:djComboBox id="djComboBox2" tabIndex="2"></xe:djComboBox>
<xe:djComboBox id="djComboBox3" tabIndex="1"></xe:djComboBox>
```

Comment: I am an idiot, just checked my code and I had "tabindex" instead of "tabIndex". Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I never used them and have to DDE available yet but can you define the tabindex attribute via the attrs property list of the control?

Comment: This probably would have worked too, but I had the attribute wrong see above.